# Error "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred."

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I've spent days trying to launch any Android program. Even "Hello World" gives me the same error:

> "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred".

I'm running Eclipse v3.5 (Galileo), Google APIs 2.2.8, on a Windows XP machine.

I've used all the tricks I can find on the web: the command line "adb kill-server", the DDMS "reset ADB", I started the emulator both before and after Eclipse, and searched for ports being used by other programs.

What is going on here? Is there a magic combination of versions of Eclipse, Java, ADB, emulator, and whatever else that works?

Comment: Is your emulator showing up in the devices command? - `# adb devices`

Comment: If all you are doing is android development you may just want to download Motodev for Android.  Then all this is preconfigured for you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the devices command. I do see Google APIs as a AVD in the "Android SDK & AVD Manager" window, and I can start it from there as well.

Comment: I ran the adb devices command and received "error: write failure during connection".

Comment: Thanks Jim for trhe heads-up on the Motodev site. They make it a lot easiler to install all of the packages. However, the same problem exists. I guess its the same Eclipse with the same unstable adb. Any help is much appreciated. Im on day 3 of this problem.

Comment: Cleaning project did work for me.

Answer (score 532, accepted):

Try the below steps:

1. Close Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in the command prompt
3. Type `adb kill-server` (**Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands**)
4. Then type `adb start-server`
5. No error message is thrown while starting the ADB server, then ADB is started successfully.
6. Now you can start Eclipse again.

It worked for me this way.

Restart your phone as well!

Comment: in mac it was a bit more simple,i went to the directory tools inside Android sdk. Then i click on adb file and start the eclipse again.

Comment: Adb has been moved from /tools/ to /platform-tools/

Comment: This didn't help me. I've got the 'ADB server didn't ACK'. The computer reboot helped ;)

Comment: When I did adb start-server, I got an error: ADB server didn't ACK.  Failed to start daemon.

Comment: For 64 bit Ubuntu users ensure that *ia32-libs* package is installed. `apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: I also got the same error as Igor G. * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *

Comment: Ok I solved my issue. I go to Task Manager in windows7 -> processes -> selected the adb.exe -> End Process. After that I go to cmd prompt and type adb start-server. This time adb statred succefully. I run eclipe and it was showing no error.

Comment: I can't begin to explain how many times `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` have fixed my problem!

Comment: If not solved, check for any other processes you have running that have adb in their title. For me it was SnapPea.

Comment: I found you don't need to navigate to the directory to launch the command prompt, you can launch it and run the adb commands from anywhere.

Comment: However, there is one problem: there is a 50-50 chance for this solution. Even if the adb is fixed, still disconnects suddenly. Overall, adb sudden disconnection is highly questionable. I tried your solution but still no work.

Comment: Can someone explain why this happens in the first place?

Comment: recently i found this problem many time I start working my pc. what is the problem and how can solve to do not need to I try commands? to day this wont work and i get the message say that "faild to start deamon" :(

Comment: my problem is solved! it because of port confilict with another app

Comment: if you are using genymotion this [link](http://codetheory.in/adb-genymotion-upgrade-issue-devices-not-showing-up/) is very helpful

Comment: This was handy, I got "adb server is out of date.  killing..." so I updated and problem solved!

Answer (score 106):

Use:

> Open Task Manager → Processes → adb.exe → End Process → restart Eclipse

This worked for me.

And:

> Open Task Manager →  Processes → eclipse.exe → End Process → restart Eclipse

Comment: This worked for me. adb kill-server on the command line didn't do it for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is the only way that works for my case (Eclipse: Indigo, OS: Win7 64-bit)

Comment: I don't see a process named "adb.ext" in my task manager. Emulator is running though.

Comment: "adb.exe" ... search it in running processes ..not in open windows section in Task manager.

Comment: this method worked for me also while using eclipse juno. Thank you

Comment: on the mac side, can use 'Activity Monitor' (works like windows task manager).

Answer (score 24):

Open up the Windows task manager, kill the process named adb.exe, and re-launch your program.

Comment: I see you're a new user here. Answers with big green checks by them mean the person has accepted them.  When adding answers to a question with an accepted answer be certain that your answer has some substantial difference, be it the clarity of the explanation, detail or approach taken.  I hope you enjoy your stay here!

Comment: Thanks.  My approach here does not involve re-starting Eclipse (faster), locating the ADB SDK tools directory at a command prompt and typing two commands (also faster).  In other words, it is one step instead of the original six. Despite the original poster's acceptance of an answer, I thought this approach was a substantial enough addition (for those using Windows, at least) to warrant posting.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work, this did, thanks - Eclipse "Indigo" win7

Comment: By "relaunch your program", do you mean restart Eclipse, or run the Android application I am writing in Eclipse, again?

Answer (score 12):

> [2012-07-04 11:24:25 - The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred. 
>   [2012-07-04 11:24:25 - You must restart adb and Eclipse. 
>   [2012-07-04 11:24:25 - Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/ASDK/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed

I realized the folder of the project in Eclipse was closed. I expanded the directory and the project launched. I know this may sound like a "no-brainer". I had the .java files open on the workspace, and that was enough to make me think the project was open.

Answer (score 10):

I tried this using Eclipse Juno and it worked fine:

- From the dropdown of the Run icon, select option Run Configuration.
- Make sure your project is selected
- Go to tab Android
- Under section Launch Action, select Launch Select the package name
  and voila! try running your application.

**UPDATE:** It also helps to kill the process adb.exe from the task manager and restart it.  adb.exe can be found here: Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.

Good luck

Answer (score 7):

Update your Eclipse Android development tools. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure it's not running in the task-manager processes. If so, end the process and then start it from a command prompt as in a previous answer. This worked for me.

Comment: Please pay attention to the date of the original question.  This question was answered over a year ago with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my situation: I have the same warning:
*The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured*

I have found the solution:

The adb.exe was moved from: `android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe` to
                              `android-sdk-windows\platform-tool\adb.exe`.

Only thing. Move file `adb.exe` to `\tools`. And restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has already been answered, but thought I might add that I found the problem to be folder permissions on my `android-sdk` directory.

I tested it out by granting Full Control to Everyone (dodgy, I know...), and the problem went away. I am not sure yet what the specific mix of permissions might be that it was looking for, but I assume some or other service in Eclipse didn't have execute permissions on adb.exe. That said, I'm a complete noob to this - just wanted to put it out there in case someone else had some insights into this.

I am running Windows 7, 64-bit, 4.2.0 Eclipse, and 20.0.0v201206242043 ADT.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to the folder `platform-tools` in `cmd` folder platform tools available in the Android folder where you have Android backup files.
2. Type the following

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```

   and

   ```
   adb start-server
   ```

   then type

   ```
   adb devices

   adb kill-server
   ```

You can now see your device.

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been plaguing me for days until I finally figured out what was causing it. It got so bad I couldn't even update my apps even after trying all the above suggestions.

HTC Sync also runs a process called adb.exe. HTC Sync is an optional program available when installing the HTC USB driver. I had recently updated my installation of the HTC bundle and apparently hadn't installed HTC Sync before. Checking properties on adb.exe in the Task Manager showed it to belong to HTC Sync, not Android.

As soon as I uninstalled HTC Sync from the control panel the problem disappeared! (It's listed separately from the USB driver so that can stay.) I never saw more than one instance of adb.exe running. I'm curious to know if people having to kill the process from Task Manager, check to see if it's actually the Android process you are killing?

Please read user comments (I too have a HTC Thunderbolt):
http://www.file.net/process/adb.exe.html

Answer (score 2):

Simply go in `Task Manager` (windows users) and kill the `abd.exe` (it is remaining active somehow).
After that start `Eclipse`.

The error

> "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured"

happened after installing plugin for Android of Netbeans. After closing Netbeans the process `abd.exe` remained active. When you want to start again `Eclipse` ... you will get the error.

You have to manually kill the `adb.exe` and then start `Eclipse`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems, and it turned out that my antivirus program (Comodo) sandboxed the adb.exe, and that is why it didn't work. I closed the antivirus, and it worked just fine. Consider that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the tools folder of your Android SDK
2. Run `emulator.exe -avd <your avd>`. It will take some time for the emulator to run.
3. Once you see the homescreen on your emulator, open Eclipse and run your program again...

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that my firewall was preventing ADB from binding to the port it wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I found out that there was another adb.exe running which was started from BirdieSync (Sync Tool for Thunderbird). I found out with [Process Explorer](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip) from Sysinternals, that Windows was running another incompatible adb.exe. Just put the mouse cursor above the process (in Process Explorer), and you'll see which adb.exe is started.

I had to kill the BirdieSync process as well, because it started the wrong adb.exe again.

Then I could start the right adb.exe, and it worked fine.

Comment: I now got the point about stackoverflow: i am really too late und the question ist already marked "solved". But it helped me to find my error and i wanted to help too. Better Luck next Time!

Answer (score 1):

The killing of the mysteriously running abd.exe worked. This sudden roadblock stopped me for a long time. I was doing all sorts of command line stuff and removed the lock icon from my user folder, but nothing worked until your simple suggestion of looking for the abd in the running processes of the task manager and killing it.

Another newbie roadblock I discovered an answer to: don't run Eclipse when any file other than the main .java file is active. If you run it when, for example, the main.xml file is active, you will get unhelpful error messages, an odd file created like main.xml.out, and it wont run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

1. I entered Task manager -> find adb.exe -> end process
2. Go to the Android SDK tools directory in Command Prompt double click adb.exe

That's all

Answer (score 1):

I found the path of the SDK (Preferences* → *Android* → *SDK Location*) was the cause. My SDK path was the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

The spaces in the path is the problem. To get it to work, you must change `Program Files (x86)` to `Progra~2`

The complete right path is `C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk`.

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions will probably work. I solved it downloading the latest ADT (Android Developer Tools) and overwriting all files in the SDK folder.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once you overwrite it, Eclipse may give a warning saying that the path for SDK hasn't been found, go to *Preferences* and change the path to another folder (C:), click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, and then change it again and set the SDK path and click <kbd>Apply</kbd> again.

Answer (score 1):

Close Eclipse

Use this in the terminal:

```
sudo killall -9 adb
```

Run Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Genymotion emulator:

Make sure that the SDK path used for Genymotion is also the same path used for the Eclipse.

This error also occurs if those two paths are different.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Eclipse Neon2. on Mac OS 10.12.4 and I experienced this issue after recently upgrading my Android SDK to the latest "SDK Tools" (v 25.2.5), "Platform tools" (v 26) and "Build Tools" (v 26) and moving one of my development projects to Android Studio.

Unfortunately none of the many answers here worked for me.

What **did** work was to create a **separate** copy of the Android SDK in a different folder and then point Eclipse to it via "Preferences --> Android". You will have to use an older version of the SDK as indicated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43073408/1232524).

Once you've downloaded the separate version of the SDK and put it in a different folder than your main Android SDK, launch the SDK Manager (via `<separate-sdk>/tools/android`) and install the required "Platform tools", "Build-tools" and Android versions. There are two important things to observe here though:

1. Make sure that you **do not** upgrade your "SDK Tools" beyond the version that's already installed!
2. Make sure that you install a version of the "Build tools" that is **less than** 26!

Otherwise you may run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder).

Answer (score 0):

maydenec is correct (in my case...). The file was moved.

I even found this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\adb_has_moved.txt
```

Which explained this issue.

Suggestions in this file:

1. **Install** "Android SDK Platform-tools".
2. Please also **update** your PATH environment variable to
   include the "platform-tools/" directory.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to start my AVD emulator first (from the AVD manager), and then to run my program. The other stuff mentioned here.

(Restarting the ADB server didn't work though.)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse → *preferences* → *Android* → *NDK*

Check the "NDK Location" path is set correctly, and use the browse button to set it.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidSDK → *Platform Tools* → *Kill* did not work.

But after restarting my computer, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me, even restarting a computer. I couldn't install an app on my device. But I solved this problem by myself:

Go to DDMS and choose connected device. Now try again!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. My resolution is to set the directory `platform-tools` to the system path and then restart the OS.

Or in a DOS cmd prompt:

```
set path=%path%;c:\xxx\platform-tools
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android-sdks/platform-tools` to the Windows PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above methods, end the adb process through task manager and all, it didn't work. But when I ran the adb.exe file as admin  it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your firewall didn't add a rule and blocked the connection to adb server. It uses newdev.dll and your network. It just happened here, I removed the blocking rule from the firewall, and now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted all my tasks from HTC task manager and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, you can run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I run to restart adb (Android Debug Bridge) server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Summary: restart adb (Android Debug Brdige) server.

## adb binary full path
ADB_BIN=./adb


if pgrep adb >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "adb is running"
    echo "terminating adb ..."
    $ADB_BIN kill-server
    if pgrep adb >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        echo "did not work"
        echo "kill adb processes by killall"
        killall -9 adb
    else
        echo "terminated"
    fi
else
    echo "adb is not running"
fi

echo "starting adb ..."

$ADB_BIN start-server

echo "adb process:"

echo `pgrep adb`

echo "done"

# END
```

Answer (score 0):

Devices window → toolbar more menu → Reset adb

For displaying the devices window: Menu *Window* → *Show view* → *Other* → *Android* → *Devices*

Answer (score 0):

Another error cause would be the fact you might have set up adb.exe to run with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I faced this problem, was solved with adb restart. If you have tried `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` with no luck you might want to try this. When again I faced the same issue I tried all the above answers, with no luck, and this was the last option to try. It did work like a charm.

Goto **Android SDK Manager** >> **Install the essential packages.**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried "adb kill-server" and restarted Eclipse too many times. I even rebooted my computer. They don't work.

Finally, I turned off test mode of my phone and turned on again. Then everything looked fine.