# SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar android

Tags: java, android, error-handling, adt

Yesterday evening I upgrade to `ADT-21` and restarted eclipse. Then eclipse said that you need to update android tool to version 21. I downloaded `window_installer21` and install it in the same location where my previous window_installer was installed. So it overwrite the file. Then I restarted eclipse and suddenly all project stop working. Eclipse always open with the error.
     `SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar`

And when i try to launch a project it stops with the below error
     `Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!`

SDK Manager is also not opening.

I have tried:

1. Clearing all project
2. Re stared eclipse and computer about 20-30 timmes
3. Uninstall Android SDk, JAVA and reinstalled it
4. Setting the path of find_java.bat file
5. Searched 6 hour over internet and read some form

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617830/eclipse-upgrade-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323684/error-while-creating-new-project-in-android).and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder) one also.

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A popup appears warning you to update to the latest sdk and opens the appropriate tool. Tried this (several times - restarting each time) with no effect.

Instead the answer was ..

1. In eclispe, find the location of your android sdk (Window->Preferences->Android and the SDK location is at the top of the page).
2. Close down eclispe.
3. Find the sdk on the disk - and run the standalone SDK Manager.exe (It appears to fail when first opened - but wait a second or two for the gui to appear). Note - this is the same gui that was previously opened by eclipse!
4. Take all the updates as recommended. A dialog box appears indicating that the management tool itself has been updated and should be restarted.
5. Restart the tool - take any more updates recommended and close.
6. Start eclipse - the problem has gone away!

Answer (score 0):

try to install fresh andoridSDK. the problem is with SDK and not with your eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Toady when i stared eclipse all things become normal.Now all projects are working but still android sdk manager is not opening.

Comment: why you want to open the androidsdk? do you mean to say that from eclipse -> windows -> preferences -> android -> while selecting here it is not showing the sdk options?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android tool/sdk with latest and create new  workspace .it solved problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I you got the same error message, but SDK manager works for you, run it with administrator privileges and delete both packages in Tools folder. Then install them again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem after installing the latest Android/Eclipse direct from the Android developer site. I was also seeing another error related to find_java claiming it couldn't find Java in c:\windows\system32\java.exe. I had previously used MOTODEV studio a year ago (haven't touched it since). I was concerned it might cause a conflict, so I uninstalled it. However it left some bits and pieces in my c:\Users\ folder. I blew away some hidden directories related to android, as well as an androidsdks directory that had been installed there and likewise blew away my workspace folder. Then I launched Eclipse/SDK Manager and all was right with the world :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I got this issue I started using Google ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

- **Update Eclipse Packages:** `Help > Check for Updates`
- **Update Android SDK:** `Window > Android SDK Manager`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the existence of an older version of `dx.jar` in the VirtualStore (a folder where windows stores user versions of system and program files).
Go to `"C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\<android-sdk path>"` and delete all the content, or just the `"\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar"` file.

i.e: if your user name is `"user32"` and your android SDK is placed in `"C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk"`, after the update you'll probably have an obsolete version of `dx.jar` in `"C:\Users\user32\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Java\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\"`

Answer (score 0):

If the .jar file could not load try this..

locate **android-sdks\build-tools\28.0.3\lib**

delete the dx.jar file

Select the appropriate sdk tools that your android application works with thorugh sdk manager

Again search for

Here i am using *apk 21.0.1*

locate **android-sdks\build-tools\21.0.1\lib**

Cut the dx.jar file and paste it in the  **android-sdks\build-tools\28.0.3\lib** folder