# Error:Android Dex: Cannot find file \android-sdk-path\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar

Tags: android

I got the latest Android SDK several days ago. I encountered the problem such as the title when I build my android application with Intellij IDEA. I knew the latest android sdk move the dx.jar from platform-tools to a new folder called build-tools. So i want to know how to fix it?

Comment: I think the following link will solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743394/securityexception-unable-to-find-field-for-dex-jar-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of people encountered this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107311

It is fixed in IDEA 12.1.4, which you can get at by changing your update settings to "early access". It'll probably be on the main feed shortly. If on linux or mac, you could also set up a symbolic link so the old path resolves. Probably best to just update to the latest version.

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much. I turned to use Android Studio instead of Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem:

```
Android Pre Dex: Cannot find file D:\sdk\sdk\platform-tools\dx.jar
```

I resolved it in a simple way. File dx.jar located in **D:\sdk\sdk\platform-tools\lib** . 
I moved it in the parent directory. Now it works.