# Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder in my eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am getting this error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder! Sample1     Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

before some time it was working fine for me and I think due to some virus or something my setup got effected please help me on this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me.

I removed build automatically and then build whole workspace some how it worked for me :)

Comment: where is build automatically? :S

Comment: In eclipse we have options like File,Edit,Refactor etc in that list we have Project also click on that Project tab, then you will have Build Automatically option their.

Answer (score 4):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960943/953105) provides more details if removing build automatically / rebuilding doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

from [Android ADT error, dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder/8960943#):

"add this in the project.properties of your project:
sdk.buildtools=25.0.2"

Answer (score 1):

File-> Switch Workspace-> (new workspace)
it will definitely work :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Android SDK Manager.(Windows → Android SDK manager)
2. Go to Tools → Options.
3. Click on Clear Cache → Close.
4. Go to Packages → Reload.

Packages will be visible now under the latest downloads in SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of the things but nothing worked for me. After spending some time i got the solution

Open `{Android SDK dir}\build-tools` and also open `project.properties` in our project

Check for `sdk.buildtools=29.0.0` (If you don't have this, just add it manually)
Change `29.0.0` entry based on `{Android SDK dir}\build-tools` folder and start the build

**Ex:**

- {Android SDK dir}\build-tools i have 28.0.3. Then I've changed sdk.buildtools=28.0.3 gave the build. Not worked
- {Android SDK dir}\build-tools i have 25.0.3. Then I've changed sdk.buildtools=25.0.3 gave the build. Not worked
- {Android SDK dir}\build-tools i have 24.0.3. Then I've changed sdk.buildtools=24.0.3 gave the build. Success

Answer (score 0):

After trying all these,yet haven't solve my problem then i change the SDK LOCATION:
Do change the windows -> preferences-> Android-> change the SDK LOCATION FROM.It work for me

Answer (score 0):

The only solution worked for me was removing the impacted versions from build tools folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `project.properties` file and add the following line

```
sdk.buildtools=25.0.3
```