# dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-sdk-tools, dx

I have an old project, which was made in Eclipse Luna.

Now when I open it in this version of Eclipse or in Eclipse Photon, then such an error occurs "Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!".

This error occurs when the project is compiled.

I know that there are already some questions/answers about it in this forum but they didn't work for me.

The methods I tried:

1. Reset Android SDK
2. Reset Eclipse
3. Clean project
4. [Android ADT error, dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder)
5. https://www.buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-to-solve-it-the-file-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder.10509/
6. http://davidcrowley.me/?p=663
7. https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/aa933f
8. [Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder in my eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025404/unable-to-build-the-file-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder-in-my-eclips)
9. [Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009679/unknown-error-unable-to-build-the-file-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-fold)

Comment: I would recommend just creating a new project and copy/importing/whatever the source from the old one.

Comment: I tried this option and it does not work.

Comment: Then your problem has nothing to do with importing an old project, but with how your environment is set up in general :)

Comment: That is, this problem is how Eclipse is installed, right?
I installed Eclipse Luna 4.4 and Eclipse Photon (now this is the newest version). In both cases, this problem arises.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with eclipse, so I don't have any tips for you. But Android Studio is the supported IDE now. Have you considered switching? Personally, I much prefer it to eclipse.

Comment: Yes, initially I was trying to open this project in Android Studio, but there was a problem in dx.jar.