# In eclipse-Android 4.2-Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder

Tags: android

I have updated Android 4.2 SDK using SDK Manager and ADT 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525 in Eclipse(Indigo).

I have created a New project,build and try to run this. I got error as

[2012-11-15 11:38:19 - MyApp] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

How to solve this issue? I have googled lot.But i am not found any correct way to solve this issue. I have clean project and tried,that also not works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1.** Open Android SDK Manager.

**2.** Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd>.

**3.** Click on <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd> → <kbd>Close</kbd>.

**4.** Go to Packages → Reload.

You should now see more packages available under "Android 4.2 (API17)" and you should be able to install them without a problem.

Comment: thank you! this had me going crazy, why do I ever update this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday when I updated Eclipse and not the Android SDK. Ensure that your Android SDK is updated. Otherwise you might want to look at this answer..

[Android ADT error, dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder)

Comment: I already have dx.jar in following location.C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\lib

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me as well, try closing and relaunch eclipse.

Clean the project and run.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no lib folder in platform-tools folder, so I just create a new lib folder  in platform-tools folder and paste dx.jar which I had found in buildtools folder in that lib folder.......And its work for me :)