# dx.failed error show up when i'm exporting apk file by ecilpse

Tags: eclipse

As I exported the APK file in Eclipse, an error message showed up saying `dx.failed`. Just that one word. I googled about this, and someone recommended reinstalling the Android SDK playform-tools. So tried it and yet it changed nothing.

Anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't support eclipse anymore. I would highly recommend you to use Android studio. However, you may find the solution in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder)