# Running an application in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to run a simple android application in eclipse.I got these errors while trying to run.Help me.Thanks in Advance.[Errors shown while running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6tOo.png)

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAegI.png)

[Graphical Layout Of My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjpfq.png)

Comment: check the sdk path , update the sdk then clean project and run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ADT error, dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228453/android-adt-error-dx-jar-was-not-loaded-from-the-sdk-folder)

Comment: Just interested is there any specific reason for using eclipse and not Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Find your latest dx.jar in {Android SDK dir}\platforms*

and copy it to:

{Android SDK dir}\platform-tools\lib\

Restart eclipse, clean your project and everything should work as expected.

AND

Use Android Studio as google has stopped given support to eclipse.
if you would solve this error probably any other dependency error would come.

Comment: I cant find dx.jar in platform tools.ERRORS:[2018-06-12 17:21:13 - Dex Loader] Failed to load C:\Users\tmshr\android-sdks\build-tools\28.0.0\lib\dx.jar.[2018-06-12 17:21:13 - MyApp] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

Comment: Bro what are the minimum requirements for runnng android studio.I face many problems even in Android Studio.Plz dont give the normal answer"Google it !You'll find it."