# error "The connection to adb is down" when run an android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, adt

I'm new with android development, and I have problems installing all the recent platform. I'm a java developer that I would like learning android.

I've installed all programs succesfully in windows xp sp3 (JDK 1.6 with environment vars created, eclipse 3.5, 3.6 & 3.7 well configured, Android SDK with all the features, devices, platform-tools, APi's, etc, and ADT Plugin 12 for eclipse with an emulator to API 8 -Target 2.2-), but, when I'm running an android project into eclipse (Run -> Android Application), the eclipse console show me: "**The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has ocurred... You must restart adb and eclipse... Ensure that adb is in this path 'D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe'**" (or something similiar).

I'm very sure that the path is right, adb is correctly running on command-line, and the commands 'adb kill-server' and 'adb start-server' works fine, but doesn't solve my problem (like I've read in other answers).

The emulator, via Eclipse, not working, but if I start the emulator via Eclipse ADV Manager, emulator starts fine, but when I runs the android app, I take the same error.

I suppose that Eclipse can't start adb,but I don't know why.

Other issue, when I executed 'adb devices', console show me an empty list, no 'no devices' message, but when I plugged my HTC, adb is running fine in console, but Eclipse doesn't.

In addition, I also try restarting adb with Eclipse - Devices tab, but the list of devices are empty too.

Anyone can help me, please? I've read so much that my eyes are pixelated. xD

Best regards!!

PD: sorry, but my english is a bit poor ;)

Comment: go to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured . you l find your answer

Answer (score 9):

in the DDMS perspective (if it doesn't show, add it by click window>open perspective>other...>DDMS)
then click the triangle of the devices tab > reset adb.
this works for me.

[image]

Comment: thats solved my problem. even the restart adb from command prompt and eclipse restart didnt work but this one was just perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I finally resolved the problem, please see my [blog](http://huluyige.blogspot.fr/2013/03/android-error-connection-to-adb-is-down.html)

you can do this steps to solve the problem:

- task manager-> process
- right click on adb.exe and left click on "properties"
- check the path of the process:

  -if the path is like "Programs\android-sdk\platform-tools", which means it is the android sdk that is running this process.

  -if not, that means there is another process this is running adb.exe, you have to kill the process or service which runs adb.exe.(you can identify the process by the path)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too. The solution I've found is to kill eclipse, open up task manager and kill the adb.exe process. Then when you start eclipse again, that should also kick start adb and it should work from there.

Comment: I've also tried this, and I take the same error... when I started Eclipse again it can't running adb.exe process in Task Manager.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand you, is adb in the processes again?

Comment: No, adb process not starting with eclipse. adb process only starts when emulator starts manually with ADV Manager from eclipse Preferences menu

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to go to Help-> Check for updates and making sure everything is up to date.

Comment: everything is up to date in eclipse

Comment: I installed android and programs this morning, so I think is all updated

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps :

```
- Close Eclipse IDE
- Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
- run adb kill-server
- run adb start-server
- Now start Eclipse again.
```

Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in Windows7

1. Close all opened emulators
2. Go to task manager > processes and then click on adb.exe and press the button 'end process'.
3. Then go to command prompt go to plate-form tools and type

   ```
   adb start-server
   ```
4. Then run your application through eclipse.

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

you try
Open Task Manager > Processes > eclipse.exe > End Process > restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the FIREWALL!.Turn off your windows firewall , Then restart adb and eclipse from task-manager