# Run application in Eclipse opens a new copy of the emulator instead of the running one

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have some new strange Eclipse behavior from yesterday. When I want to run an application and click on the green arrow (the run icon), it opens additional emulator copy instead to run application. I deleted from `avd` folder snapshot and user-data images, but I still have this bug. Any ideas why it happened and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: is your already running device shown in devices panel?

Comment: Try setting Run Configurations if you haven't tried it already.

Comment: better run on a device instead of emulator !

Comment: @Snicolas: Not a helpul comment. Many developers would like to have a box full of real devices running various versions of Android so they can test things. Unless you're personally prepared to fund everyone I guess people will just have to run with AVD emulation.

Comment: Hi Insaurabh. Yes, I have one device that is already opened, but I put attention that this device is undefined in DDMS.

Comment: Hi Ghost, I agree with you that I need an emulator. I tried to do it now as Sam.Janz wrote, but the bug is still happens.

Comment: Hi CasperOne and Vincents. I understood, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I learned from them additional nice features. Finally, I reinstalled eclipse and sdk ( the only sdk reinstall didn't help).

Comment: This question is allready answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041915/eclipse-keeps-starting-new-emulators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

click on the down arrow beside that green play button and select the option "Run Configurations..." when window opens selct the tab "target" beside android tab and then below the line "Deployement Target Selection Mode" select the radio button having title "Manual" and the click "Apply" button which is at bottom and then close the window. so next time whenever you click the run button (Green Button with play icon) the eclips will ask you to run the project on a running emulator or start a new emulator to run project. i think this can solve your problem.

Comment: Hi SamJanz.Thank you for very good and detailed explanation. I learned when I tried it the new eclipse features. It still same bug. But I put my attention that DDMS doesn't recognize any of opened devices.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please verify that you are running the correct version of AVD.
2. Please check if your adb is running properly.

Some times all you need to do is force restart your adb

use commands

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

this should help, as its gonna restart your adb.

In case you are still not able to find the devices under ddms control try to see if your firewall if blocking the adb connection.

Comment: Hi Abhinava, thanks for the answer. Where should I run these commands? In android-sdk/tools folder in cmd?

Comment: You have to run this from the command prompt. If you already have the added adb to you env path, then from anywhere it should work or else from the android-sdk/platform-tools