# Eclipse and simulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

Excuse me, i have a problem. When i push "run" to run a project in eclipse, in console it appear this error:

```
    [2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] 
[2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-11-09 14:26:27 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What i must do to resolve this problem? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Try to delete emulator and create a new.

Comment: maybe this answer has some insight to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041915/eclipse-keeps-starting-new-emulators

Answer (score 0):

Delete this virtual device and make it again.

Comment: and have got same result?

Comment: Yes, i got same result