# Unable to detect Android phone in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have been developing in Android for approximately two months now. Yesterday, my eclipse starting giving me the error:

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

So I followed the steps for restarting adb located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured).

Eclipse now gives me:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
```

My phones, however, are not being detected. I have a Galaxy S2 running Android 2.3.4 stock, and a S2 rooted running 4.0.3. Neither are being detected. On my home pc, both work fine in eclipse.

I have tried restarting my laptop, and even tried killing adb and eclipse and retrying the steps above. But it still won't detect my phones. My emulators are working fine. It is worth noting that the `severe error has occurred` seems to come back when I restart my laptop.

Comment: Do you have the `Samsung kies`

Comment: If you run adb devices, do you have empty list, or not empty, but with offline devices?

Comment: Settings > Applications > Development > allow debugging, i beleive

Comment: @POMATu: I have an empty list

Comment: @SpK: I dont have Kies, but i find it extremely unusual that it would work for 2 months then suddenly stop. I have had no system changes whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Device driver provided by samsung in your laptop.

You can install [Samsung kies](http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/&ei=zyngT9qyLqHbmAWdosGnDQ&usg=AFQjCNHazetOF2tlvHsxw4ptEdLDgjmDtA&sig2=BWFG0yGhdnBl9wsnSWvmwg) it also installs the device driver

Comment: I'll try Kies, but i find it extremely unusual that it would work for 2 months then suddenly stop. I have had no system changes whatsoever.

Comment: Try to reboot your device and connect it to your PC

Comment: Also, try to install this driver

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?cntsId=9480&platformId=1

Comment: Samsung Kies seems to have done the trick. I do wish I knew what caused this though.

Answer (score 0):

Install driver for your device if you already have driver means try to update your driver manually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the samsung usb cable? try to use a non-Samsung one, I had a very similar issue and it worked for me.