# error the connection to adb is down and severe error has occured

Tags: android

hi i am new to android and am trying to run a simple program. there is no error in a program but while running  i am getting a error like

[2013-07-21 11:57:43 - program name] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2013-07-21 11:57:43 -  program name] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-07-21 11:57:43 -  program name] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

i have searched many forums and it was given that to specify the path name correctly. my path name i specified it correctly but my adb.exe file is not running when i see in the task manager. can anyone pls help me to fix the error.

Comment: Go to cmd and type `adb` and see what you get

Comment: As u have suggested  i checked with adb ,but am able to see a lot of options.can u please briefly explain which option to choose and guide further

Comment: but my android is luanching. after the android launch am getting this errors.

Comment: I was just testing if adb was on your PATH, which it is. From cmd run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`

Comment: i tried that too but nothing works.. i tried in task manager also but there is no processes like adb.exe is running.

Answer (score 0):

["The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

You might want to end all the adb proccesses you see on task manager before starting adb again.