# Error the connection to adb is down

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have a problem in eclipse

```
[2013-08-03 21:21:42 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2013-08-03 21:21:42 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
[2013-08-03 21:21:44 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2013-08-03 21:21:44 - adb] * failed to start daemon *
```

I did like this solutions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-sever-error-has-occured)

and also same error and restart my laptop and also delete adb and download it again but when try run any program see that

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.

```
[2013-08-03 21:27:19 - ] You must restart adb and Eclipse. 
[2013-08-03 21:27:19 - ] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at
```

and it is in correct location so what can I do ?!

Comment: If you are on windows go to your sdk path folder then `Shift+RightClick` your sdk folder, click `Open Command Window Here` then Type `adb kill-server`, hit `Enter`, then type `adb start-server`, hit `Enter`. Also check On Eclipse `Preference>>Android>> SDK Location` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open your terminal
2. cd ~/.../adt-bundle/sdk/tools/
3. adb kill-server
4. adb start-server