# Eclipse Error Log is gone crazy

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, error-log

the other day i was editing a layout when suddendly eclipse freeze for a long time and when it came back I couldn't run the application nor edit the layout anymore. I reboot my PC and I was able again to run the app but the LogCat doesn't work anymore.

This are some screens:

[image][image]

Can somebody tell me what is happening ?

Comment: Restarting adb helps a lot with android problems, the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-sever-error-has-occured) is worth a try.

Comment: This is not the LogCat, it's just to display error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open CMD and write `adb -d logcat <your package name>:<log level> *:S`. If you don't get any logs maybe your Android SDK is somehow broken or damaged and try reinstalling it.