# android emulator won't start

Tags: android, windows, android-virtual-device

I am trying to start an Android Virtual Device from the Android Virtual Device Manager.  The Android Emulator window opens, but the screen remains on the Android logo and does not progress further.

It was working fine until started a second avd. Now first avd and second avd won't start. Restarted windows machine but seems to have no effect.

Comment: kill adb and then restart adb again

Comment: [Killing ADB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094080/1293492) doesn't help in my case. All I see is: "java.io.IOException: A felépített kapcsolatot az állomás szoftvere megszakította". Which translates to something like "the established connection has been terminated by the station's software".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy and delete `.android` folder in your documents. Then start again.

Comment: Faster than copy-delete: rename in command promt using this. `rename %USERPROFILE%\.android .androidBAK`.

Comment: Doesn't help in my case. All I see is "Waiting for target device to come online". No AVD errors, nothing special in Event Log or Gradle Console, just a warning: "Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.". My other Virtual Device works perfectly.

Comment: Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: If you do that then it deletes all AVD definition and you can't start any. `>emulator @android4
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [android4], use -list-avds to see valid list.
HOME is defined but there is no file android4.ini in $HOME\.android\avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd, and $HOME\.android\avd)`

Answer (score 2):

DDMS -->devices -->restart adb

Comment: This way it's easier for me to find it in Android Studio 2.0:
Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor > Devices (the left panel) > little white down arrow > Reset adb. Still, it doesn't work, I get an error. "Error while waiting for device: adb connection not available, or was terminated."

Comment: I had just restarted my computer and then started to get this message. Resetting adb worked 4 me.

Comment: +1 to @TamásBolvári  - this solved the problem for me but I was only able to find this using the Android Studio menus he described. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this... It worked for me. In your android emulator settings double VM heap value. If current value is 32, make it 64 and then start your emulator.

Comment: Doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Which one? In `config.ini` or `hardware-qemu.ini`? It's in both places.