# Android 5.0 Emulator won't start

Tags: android, windows-8.1, emulation

For my work project I received I'd need to use the emulator as the company does not have a 5.0 device yet.

But when I try to start it, it loads infinitely. I've checked the logs, and it reboots because of this: http://pastebin.com/yCjiAaPR

Has anyone ran into this issue and solved it yet?

PS: Latest Android SDK, fresh updated! Computer is a Lenovo G50-70, target is ARMv7 with 2gb ram.

Comment: Please try genymotion. Probably It works faster than your mobil phone.

Answer (score -1):

Use the GenyMotion emulator instead it is VERY fast, very easy .If you insist to use it then this can be due to the reason that you don't have enough RAM. also try this solution if it still don't work

[android emulator won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169478/android-emulator-wont-start)

Comment: I've tried running it multiple times (the standard emulator), and the third or fourth time it booted. I will also try the Genymotion one. RAM can't be an issue, got 8GB, and allocated 2GB to it which worked fine.

Comment: Except it is not. Tried with multiple targets, the virtual machines never start. The VirtualBox console screen says that a v86d binary couldn't be started or found.