# Android adb doesn't start

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm using android adt bundle and installed Android 4.4.2(API 19) to my computer. Following is a screen shot of my installed packages.

[image]

Once I'm going to run a android application using my emulator(I created a emulator using AVD Manager) it gives me the error

```
[2014-03-12 23:12:58 - DemoAndroid] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-03-12 23:12:58 - DemoAndroid] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-03-12 23:12:58 - DemoAndroid] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

**I double checked the C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe location and there exists a adb.exe.**

Once I'm running the eclipse, it doesn't start the adb.exe ( I checked it in task manager ). I had to manually start it as described in this post,
["The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

Once I'm restarting the adb.exe using command prompt, I get following output in the cmd.

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

I stopped COMODO antivirus and teamviewer, and also stopped real time protection in my Avira antivirus. But none of this worked.

These are the steps I took to overcome the problem and **none of them worked**

- I copied "platform-tools" content to the "tools" folder
- killed adb and restarted adb( Got the output as described above)
- Added platform-tools path to the system variable

And BTW  I cannot open the android sdk from eclipse( But I can open it by going to the android sdk folder and clicking on "SDK Manager.exe"). But I can start the AVD Manager using eclipse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm stuck in this for weeks now..

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem. You can do one thing. I am having linux installed on my system. In linux, open android-sdk folder. In that open tools folder, then open monitor named file as 'Run in Terminal' option. It will open 'Android Device Monitor'. Here you can add emulator of different configuration. Now you have to restart the eclipse. After that avd's will be shown and you will start them. This problem occurred when you update the sdk to android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem for few days. Finally, I found that the adb.exe was added in "unrecognized files" in COMODO antivirus --> move it to trusted files will fix the problem.