# restart adb and Eclipse while trying to load emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to rum a simple hello word program.But the emulator is not getting loaded it shows an error in the logcat

```
[2014-03-26 09:48:55 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-03-26 09:48:55 - HelloWorld] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-03-26 09:48:55 - HelloWorld] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-03-26 09:48:55 - HelloWorld] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Comment: kill server and restart eclipse... follow this steps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Close the Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
3. Type adb kill-server
4. Then type adb start-server
5. No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is
   started successfully.
6. Now you can start Eclipse again.