# How to run adb commands on a machine without admin access on Windows 7?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I did set up of Android, Java and Eclipse to start up my project but soon after running my emulator a few times I got error like “The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.”

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured) and got answer but while running adb from command prompt I am getting error as "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

How to run this adb commands without admin rights on machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting error like "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." has nothing to do with your admin rights.

Follow the steps:

1. Go to folder location where your 'adb.exe' is located.
2. copy the path and open cmd prompt and paste your folder location 
   Example: C:\Users\298xxx>C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x8
   6-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
3. Run any adb command you want like 
   C:\Users\298xxx>C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools
   \adb.exe devices
   List of devices attached
   emulator-5554   device

Problem is that in machine you need to set path of ADB.exe in system properties but you didn't had access as admin which don't allowed you to open/work directly with system related things like install/uninstall/path setting and many more.

Another way to do the same is

1. press ctrl+alt+del to open task manager
2. Go to File --> New Task -- > and copy paste the path of you adb.exe (space) devices to check for devices attached to your machine.

Comment: This is what i was looking for ? Thanks for the quick reply sir actually i forgot to set path on my machine while setting up required software & ran into this issue. Now i am able to work the adb commands from cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

> but while running adb from command prompt i am getting error as "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

This is usually a path problem.

**Linux**

This is usually one of two problems on Linux.

First, `adb` is simply not on path. Its located in `<Android SDK>/platform-tools`, so `platform-tools` needs to be on path. To ensure its on path, you want something like this in your login script (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc). Below is from Mac OS X and `.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9c
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk-macosx   

export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/":"$PATH"
```

Second, the problem can occur on Linux *if* its x86_64 and you *don't* have `ia32_libs` installed. Tools like `adb` are 32-bit, so you need to install `ia32_libs` for the entire 32-bit subsystem for 64-bit Linuxes.

**Windows**

Windows has a PATH variable, and it can be adjusted per-user. Ensure `<Android SDK>/platform-tools` is on path in Windows. It would not hurt to ensure `<Android SDK>/tools` is on path also.

[image]

If you add a `%PATH%` variable, you can copy it from the System's `%PATH%` first. Then modify your copy.

Comment: Yup, this could be one of the answer for this adb not recognized issue but as you said Mac OS X. I was stuck with Windows 7 adb issue. I really appreciate your answer this could help other who can face this issue any time on MAC OS X machine.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I should have picked that up from "batch file". In that case, ensure `platform-tools` is on path in Windows. Windows has a `PATH` variable, and it can be adjusted per-user. See [Managing Environment Variables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).