# Genymotion Failed to parse the output of 'adb version' -> restart Eclipse and adb

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, genymotion

I just wanted to use the genymotion Emulator and now nothing works anymore. I downloaded genymotion and added the plugin for eclipse. Now I'm getting every time these errors:
First a dialog appears with "Failed to parse the output of 'adb version'". Then the console shows this:

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 
'.../android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

I restart my computer 2 times, restart eclipse 6-7 times. Tried to kill-server and start-server in the terminal (I was wondered, because if i'm say ./adb start-server nothing appears in the terminal, that he's something doing. He just accept the line and directly then i could enter a new line)

I checked 10 times, that the adb is in the right folder and i do any other stuff, which i could found (Update,...)

After 3,5 hours i don't feel like it. So pleeeeeeaase help me!! I really don't know, what i should try anymore!!

(I'm using a mac :D )

Comment: See the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Comment: I tried each answer, nothing help :(

Answer (score 1):

1. just go to the program files and open genymotion.exe
2. go to settings
3. go to adb
4. change to choose custom sdk
5. browse to your sdk
6. click ok

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning all your projects in Eclipse? 
Project -> Clean

Comment: A little bit better: If I'm click on play he says "Dx trouble writing output: already prepared" and tried a long time to run. But after a while I'm getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself :) -> "Just" reinstall android sdk :) .. If you doing that, you can clean up your computer and reinstall eclipse, too :) I did all and now all work's fine and fast :)