# Adb connection error eclipse on os x

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

Hello i am trying to run my android app on eclipse and i have this problem:

`The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/Users/giannis/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.`

any idea about the problem?

Comment: Have you already gone to that path and verified adb is there?

Comment: yes the adb file is in that path

Comment: Test adb from the command line to make sure it's working. Open a terminal, navigate to the platform-tools directory, and enter `./adb version`. If the command works, then it's a matter of checking eclipse's connection to adb.

Comment: running that commend the result is: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
where might me the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since adb is installed and seems to be working, Eclipse is probably having a problem finding or starting adb. First, check that Eclipse has the right location set for the sdk (Window->Preferences->Android or slightly different on Mac). I think it should based on the error message. Then, if you still can't run the app from Eclipse, try starting adb from the command line with `adb start-server`.

**EDIT:** If the app still won't run after doing the above, make sure adb is able to find your  device or emulator. Start the emulator or connect your device, then run `adb devices` from the terminal. If your device or emulator is not listed, adb can't connect to it. If it is an actual device, make sure USB debugging under developer options in the device settings is enabled.

Comment: i used commands ./adb kill-server and then ./adb start-server and then i opened eclipse but still same problem..

Comment: running the command ./adb devices the output is:
"List of devices attached " 
and no one device is showed.. i want when i run my app to start the virtual device, i don't use my phone to run the app.
i tried to install new software using this link 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
but agin it does not work...

Comment: Here is a previous post you may or may not have seen with many more possible solutions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured). The common fixes are not working, so it could be anything causing the error.