# Android can not restart adb in mac

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I use eclipse and I have this console error when I run my app.

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
 You must restart adb and Eclipse.
```

[I Googled and I found one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

I used this current answer step by step and in command I have this error
adb: command not found
I also write ls to show all files in platform-tools folder and this folder is a dab file. But I don't know why I have this problem

Answer (score 0):

every now and then it does to me.

Try this:

1. close Eclipse
2. Move to the folder of your bundle> sdk> platform-tools> click dab
3. reopen Eclipse

Comment: i  use mac  and i can't open dab file in click

Comment: You need to click on adb and you open the console

Comment: i restarted eclipse .opened dab  with terminal but nothing changed

Comment: mmm try to restart your mac but this is weird, you happen to have other emulators? For example genymotion?

Comment: Ok try this: Close Eclipse. Go to utility > monitoring activities > search and kill adb. Restart you mac