# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using eclipse for android development in windows 7. I faced the same problem before but the below link solved my problems.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094080/3870105
```

but this time it isn't working and also tried to kill **adb.exe *32** process from windows task manager. It disappears from the process list and again gets there.  So, as a result i cant run any app from eclipse. 
the erros is:

```
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\DevTools Backup\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

What to do now?

Comment: from command line navigate to android/platform_tools directory- then run 
`adb kill-server` 
`adb start-server`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure adb.exe is located on this (D:\DevTools Backup\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools) path, otherwise just copy past adb.exe on this location.

And also make sure that correctly navigate through the path on command prompt.