# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured. - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I am using `Eclipse ADT` and it was working fine for me for last 1 year, but suddenly I faced this issue, may I know `How can I resolve this` ?

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2015-12-12 09:57:13 - MyPlace] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2015-12-12 09:57:13 - MyPlace] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/system/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

Comment: Make sure adb exist at that path. Also Eclipse isn't supported anymore. Start using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps....

1. Close the Eclipse if running
2. Navigate terminal to Android SDK platform-tools directory
3. Type `adb kill-server` (**Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands**)
4. Then type `adb start-server`
5. No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.

Now you can start Eclipse again.

Otherwise you can stop adb service from System Monitor, and restart eclispe.

[For more details, click here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

Comment: can you brief this: Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt, like : Steps (I am using Ubuntu)

Comment: Oops sorry!
You can navigate terminal to android SDK directory. 
Tell me where you keep your android sdk directory, I will write the command