# Device is not showing in Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-device-monitor

Files under the device are not visible please tell me something about it
I also uploaded the screen shot of it.

[image]

Comment: Try to restart adb. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094080/2949612

Answer (score 0):

You can pull files from android device using adb command line tool. I don't know which file you exacly want. In case of sqlite database, it is stored in `//data/data/<your app>/databases/<databaseName.db>`. Probably you will need to be root to do that. Many files are hidden and inaccessible when you don't have root privileges.